# "Is a directory" error when using unlink() PHP

Tags: php, unlink, lumen-8

I'm trying a simple thing.
Get the images from a post method, move those images to my public/images folder and in case of any error that prevent the code to keep running (like the unsupported file type that I check with `preg_match()`) roll back the whole thing, in other words, delete the files that is already moved to the folder.

The thing is, when I try to use `unlink()` I got this "is a directory" error. I'm not trying to delete a directory! I'm trying to delete a file!

I made use of `is_file()`, `is_dir()`, `file_exists()` to check things out and everything points that is a file.
I spend almost all day trying to figure out what is going on but no success. I'm almost giving up this thing.

I'm on a Ubuntu 20.04, using Lumen 8 and PHP 7.4. Here's my controller code that does the thing:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Insumo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class InsumosController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->classe = Insumo::class;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $images = [
                'mainImg' => "",
                'img1' => "",
                'img2' => "",
                'img3' => "",
                'img4' => ""
            ];

            $filesKeys = $request->files->keys();

            foreach ($filesKeys as $fileKey) {
                $pattern = "/^image\/(jpeg|jpg|bmp|png|gif)$/";
                $mimeType = $request->file($fileKey)->getMimeType();

                if (!preg_match($pattern, $mimeType)) {
                    throw new \Exception('Not supported file', 415);
                }

                $insumoNome = lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', $request->nome));
                $ext = "." . $request->file($fileKey)->extension();
                $newName = $insumoNome . "-" . $fileKey . "-" . bin2hex(random_bytes(5)) . $ext;
                $images[$fileKey] = $newName;

                $request->file($fileKey)->move('images', $newName);
            }

            $insumo = Insumo::create([
                'nome' => $request->nome,
                'descricao' => $request->descricao,
                'mainImg' => $images['mainImg'],
                'img1' => $images['img1'],
                'img2' => $images['img2'],
                'img3' => $images['img3'],
                'img4' => $images['img4'],
            ]);

            DB::commit();

            return response()->json($insumo, 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            $imagesDir = __DIR__ . '/../../../public/images/';

            foreach ($images as $image) {

                if (file_exists($imagesDir . $image)) {
                    $imagesPath = $imagesDir . $image;
                    unlink($imagesPath);
                }
            }

            return response()->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

All code seems to be working as expected to me except `unlink()`.
Would some kind soul help me with this?

Comment: Post the full error message. It will include the full path of the file it's trying to unlink.

Answer (score 0):

After almost a day trying to figure out what's going on and right at the moment I submit this question pass in my mind to check my `$image` variable inside the `foreach`, and guess what?
Some times it gets empty.

Well, found the problem...